# Knowing which line i'm at in the browser/debugger in R

Tags: r, debugging, vim-plugin

This question might have a trivial answer but I haven't been able to find it.  When I'm in the browser mode debugging in R, as I press "n", I can see the current debugging line printed on screen.  But then I might do some other commands in the console but forget which line I'm on in the source code.  Is there a command I can press to reprint the line the debugger is on (or even the line #?).  I can press "n" and it will print the next line, but this isn't good always as it might jump into a long computation on the next line.

I know about the "where" command, but I dont know how to print (on command when in the browser mode) where I am within the function I'm debugging.

Before anyone tries to suggest it, I am often debugging in Neovim-R, and not using RStudio which might show the line the debugger is on (why is because I'm debugging code with huge data sets and Rstudio is slow in debugging some lines for that).

Comment: what do you mean rstudio is slow for huge data sets

Comment: Unless the bug is memory related, can you work on a smaller sample dataset first? All your operations will be much faster too.

Answer (score 0):

instead of typing `browser()`, type `thisLine <- {whatever line you're at} ; browser() ; thisLine <- NULL`
then you will have an easy way to tell. I'd recommend autohotkey to make shortcuts for this, so you can press a couple keys and `thisLine <-  ; browser() ; thisLine <- NULL` appears, then you just fill in the empty place with the line number.

Comment: What do you mean by thisLine <- {whatever line you're at} ?  Sorry, I don't follow yet what you mean?  How will this help me to see what line i'm debugging at when i've already pressed "n" several times inside some function say (or gone deeper inside another function with "s")?

Comment: I thought you were asking about when you were at the original line, then executed commands manually

Comment: Yes exactly that.  I just don't follow how to do it yet with your description?

Comment: say at line 100 in your code you put `browser()` to stop execution. Instead, put `thisLine <- 100 ; browser() ; thisLine <- NULL`
If you do that everywhere you put `browser()`, you'll always be able to check where you are, by checking the value of thisLine. If you want that to persist, of course, don't set it to NULL after. Sorry for the delay, I was making dinner